# Getting stuck with the data pre-processing code for machine learning application

Tags: python, django, machine-learning

I am currently developing a machine learning application. Please help me in this code - when i was uploading the big datasets I got an error.

The code is as follows:

```py
prep_file = Prepross.objects.get_or_create(
                filename = CurrentFile.objects.order_by('-id')[0].filename,
                coltype = request.POST.getlist('coltype'),
                assvar = request.POST.getlist('assvar'),
                missingvalues = request.POST.getlist('missingvalues'),
                trainingset_size = request.POST['trainingset_size'],
                featscaling = request.POST.getlist('featscaling'))
```

Then:

```
        # Get dataframe and change data type
        context = {}
        file_name = CurrentFile.objects.order_by('-id')[0].filename
        coltype = request.POST.getlist('coltype')
        coltype = dict([i.split(':', 1) for i in coltype])
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('media\downloaded', file_name), dtype= coltype)
        row_count = df.count()[0]

        # Keep only selected columns
        assvar = request.POST.getlist('assvar')
        xcols0 = [s for s in assvar if ":X" in s]
        xcols = [i.split(':', 1)[0] for i in xcols0]
        ycol0 = [s for s in assvar if ":y" in s]
        ycol = [i.split(':', 1)[0] for i in ycol0]
        cols = xcols + ycol
        df = df[cols]

        xcols = ', '.join(xcols)
        ycol = ', '.join(ycol)
        missing = request.POST.getlist('missingvalues')
        missing = ', '.join(missing)
        trainingset_s = request.POST.getlist('trainingset_size')
        trainingset_s = ', '.join(trainingset_s)
        testset_s = 100 - int(trainingset_s)
        feat =  request.POST['featscaling']

        # Taking care of missing data
        if missing == "no":
            if len(df) != len(df.dropna()):
                context['selecty'] = 'Your data seem to have Missing Values'
            else:
                df = df.dropna()

        # Return error if columns are not selected
        if len(ycol0) != 1:
            context['selecty'] = 'Please select one y variable'

        elif len(xcols0) < 1:
            context['selecty'] = 'Please select one or more X variables'
```

The error is:

```py
 File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProject\mlapp\views.py", line 81, in post
    coltype = dict([i.split(':', 1) for i in coltype])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
[20/Aug/2019 16:43:39] "POST /preprocessing/ HTTP/1.1" 500 81482
```

With additional lines and info on the error:

ValueError at /preprocessing/
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/preprocessing/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Exception Location: C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProject\mlapp\views.py in post, line 81
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:
['C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProject\freed',
 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages',
 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 20 Aug 2019 13:27:32 +0000

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

```
coltype = dict([i.split(':', 1) for i in coltype])
```

and is saying that one of the elements (probably the first one) has length one. This means there wasn't a ":" to split on. You're expecting each element to be of the form "a:b" but apparently that wasn't the case for one of them.

You should always validate your data before assuming that it has a certain format. In your case, one of the elements in `request.POST.getlist('coltype')` didn't have the format you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like u want to make a dictionary

```
 coltype = dict([i.split(':', 1) for i in coltype])
```

but to make a dictionary u need two argument Key and Value.
You just passing one argument. Probably, that is why, it's showing this error.